# CodeIgniter router not working

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-routing

I have a single page web site so all routes should lead to the default router. 
This is my base url:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite.cz';
```

This is a rewrite base from htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
```

And finally the routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/home'; 
$route['^/'] = "home";

$route['(.*)'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

I have also tried to replace the last line with this:

```
$route['home'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

But still when i try to type mysite.com/home i keep getting 404 message.

Any ideas what could I be doing wrong?

P.S. This all works as expected on localhost and on the test server

Comment: I assume you mean 'mysite.cz/home' right?

Answer (score 0):

I have a few sites where I route all trafic to a single controller, My routes.php looks something like this:

```
// All other routes
$route['admin'] = 'admin/home';

// Default controller Routes
$route['(:any)'] = 'home';
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

The order may matter, so I would place your default stuff at the very bottom.